# Flyway:repair is not being recognized

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, flyway

I had `V1__init.sql` script in which i was creating a table `Table1_name` with 1 column. It was running perfectly. Then i decided to change the table name and for that, I edited the `V1__init.sql` and changed the script from

`Create Table Table1_Name` to `Create Table TableName`. Now I was expecting that when i would run the project flyway would automatically detect the change and rename the table but i got some *checksum* error. After reading a little bit documentation, I learned that I need to executed `mvn flyway:repair` ... Now when I try to execute this in my project folder i get error that `flyway` is not a recognized prefix.

Why so ?

Answer (score 0):

Flyway scripts should not be modified after they've been executed.

In your example you should create a second SQL file `V2__rename_table1.sql` to rename the table.  `mvn flyway:migrate` would then detect the new script and execute it.

If you *really* need to re-run a script then doing `mvn flyway:clean flyway:migrate` should do the trick.